# SQL Server : CONTAINS returns results which containts the key after slash

Tags: sql, sql-server, contains

When I search in SQL Server for a column with a structure like this:

```
1-) 0.07.00.00-456.1/2268
2-) 20.07.00.00-0000003/8
```

with this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name tn
WHERE ((CONTAINS(tn.coulmn_name, '*8*')))
```

I expect it returns 1 and 2 rows but it only return which only come after slash  20.07.00.00-0000003/8.

I am using the syntax *blabla*, it must return with all the results which contains 8.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using contains you could use like to do what you want, you would just have to use wildcards see below:

```
Select 1
WHERE ('0.07.00.00-456.1/2268' LIKE '%8%'
AND '20.07.00.00-0000003/8' LIKE '%8%')
```

Your Code :

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name tn
WHERE tn.coulmn_name LIKE '%8%'
```

link for reading : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, but i coulnt solve why contains returns only value which is come after slash. I have used 'contains' because get results faster than 'like' searching in my data.